# Как увеличить дату

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как добавить к дате 10 дней, в колонке `date` данные хранятся в таком формате *'2022-05-16 03:00:40.139634'*. Как сделать `update` ко всем строкам таблицы на подобии такого

```
update table_name 
set date = date + INTERVAL '10 day';
```

Comment: Что значит `хранятся в таком формате`? Какой тип имеет колонка? Надеюсь, не `varchar`?

Comment: Тип колонки timestamp without time zone

Comment: https://sqlserverguides.com/postgresql-date-add/

Comment: Или просто `date + 10`, или `date + INTERVAL '10 days'`

Comment: Тестировал на селекте выдает такую ошибку `invalid input syntax for type interval: "2022-05-16 03:00:40.139634"`

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dfde15ecf582c611d5bbaa3d4ca512e0

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!!!